# Short dystopian novel about boy who lives on streets

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic, dystopia

I may not remember enough for this question to be answered.

I read this book 2 years ago; I grabbed it from a classroom library because I needed a book to read. It was definitely on the older end - at least, the copy looked like it had seen better days. I remember enjoying it, which is odd because I dislike most dystopian books - I think I grabbed it because the cover was interesting? I don't remember. It was definitely a middle grade or YA book - for kids, anyway.

It was very short (150 pages or less) and a cheap paperback. The protagonist was a younger teenager, who was living on the streets for some significant percentage of the novel. He met up with a much older man who taught him stuff (I think how to read) in this hut/hovel thing. I remember books being very important (but in a different way than Fahrenheit 451 - no one really knew how to read, I think). I think the main character narrated in first person, and it was in a sort of slang, along the lines of that in *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*, though again, not entirely sure.

> The novel ends with the older man being burned alive/tortured to death, I think, and the boy just runs off into the darkness.

I keep kind of associating this book with *Freak the Mighty* for whatever reason, but I don't know why, as I know they have very different plots.

Comment: This makes me think of The Giver, but I never read the book, so I have no idea whether it's actually similar to the description here.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I can see similarities too for sure, but I know it's not The Giver or any of its sequels.

Comment: Not a perfect fit, but maybe "Ties of Blood and Silver" from Joel Rosenberg? https://www.fantasticfiction.com/r/joel-rosenberg/ties-of-blood-and-silver.htm

Comment: @MarkSchäfer The fact that there's a completely nonhuman creature ("twice the size of a human, more than twice as strong, with frightfully glowing eyes and rows of needle-sharp teeth") does not sound right to me. I don't think that's it. Thank you though!

Comment: Could it be "The last book in the universe" by Philbrick? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Book_in_the_Universe

Comment: @C.F That’s it... if you answer I’ll accept

Comment: @heather Cool, I answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It could be The Last Book in the Universe, by Philbrick.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Book_in_the_Universe

> The protagonist was a younger teenager, who was living on the streets for some significant percentage of the novel.

The hero, Spaz, is a young boy of 14 who has epilepsy, and lives in slums, called "latches".

> He met up with a much older man who taught him stuff (I think how to read) in this hut/hovel thing. I remember books being very important (but in a different way than Fahrenheit 451 - no one really knew how to read, I think).

He tries to steal from an old man, Ryter, who is the last person to know how to read ("possesses the lost arts of literacy and literature").

> I think the main character narrated in first person, and it was in a sort of slang,

The whole book uses "sci-fi slang" to describe things: the Urb are the US, to "rip-off" is to steal, a latch-boss is a gang leader, ...

The end also fits, as

> the old man is killed, while being wheeled by jetbikes.

*found with the key words "boy meeting mentor in the streets books"*

Comment: Might be worth adding that I associated it with *Freak the Mighty* because the author's the same =) Thanks a bunch!